# Cross-compile openjdk 11u to Android device

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile openjdk 11u to android. I am using following command:

```
CC=aarch64-linux-android21-clang CXX=aarch64-linux-android21-clang++ bash configure --openjdk-target=aarch64-linux-android21 --with-toolchain-path=/mnt/d/ubuntu/NDK/build/tools/toolchain --with-sysroot=/mnt/d/ubuntu/NDK/build/tools/toolchain/sysroot  --disable-warnings-as-errors
```

but i am getting output errors below:

> checking resolved symbolic links for CC... no symlink configure: The C
> compiler (located as
> /mnt/d/ubuntu/NDK/build/tools/toolchain/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang)
> does not seem to be the required gcc compiler. configure: The result
> from running with --version was: "" configure: error: A gcc compiler
> is required. Try setting --with-tools-dir. configure exiting with
> result code 1

but if i use

```
/mnt/d/ubuntu/NDK/build/tools/toolchain/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang --version
```

the output is:

> Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8
> (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project
> 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
> Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-android21 Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /mnt/d/ubuntu/NDK/build/tools/toolchain/bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [GCC vs. Clang/LLVM: An In-Depth Comparison of C/C++ Compilers](https://medium.com/@alitech_2017/gcc-vs-clang-llvm-an-in-depth-comparison-of-c-c-compilers-899ede2be378), it is patently clear that clang is not a gcc compiler.

However, when you look at the source tree (e.g. .../jdk11/make/autoconf/toolchain.m4) there are clear signs that a clang toolchain can be used to build the JVM.  The problem appears to be that the m4 macros don't understand android as a target platform, and appear to have fallen back to trying to use gcc.

Note that the Java 11 build instructions say this:

> **clang**
>
> The minimum accepted version of clang is 3.2. Older versions will not
> be accepted by `configure`.
>
> To use clang instead of gcc on Linux, use
> `--with-toolchain-type=clang`.

---

Having said that, I don't rate your chances of getting OpenJDK Java 11 to work on Android by *simply* cross-compiling it.

There is an OpenJDK project for porting Java to mobile devices at http://openjdk.java.net/projects/mobile/ ... and they seem to have stalled at Java 9.  This suggests to me that there will be significant work to be done to get to a working OpenJDK Java 11 on Android.  You might want to touch base with that project and anyone who might still be working on it.